# C# - string.IsNullOrEmpty not working for a specific textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, isnullorempty

I'm just learning to program and I'm trying to create a program to calculate weight & balance for an aircraft. When you first load this form, I want all the textboxes specified to have a value of 0. I'm running into an issue where one of the boxes is remaining blank and not inputting 0 (Bag Weight). Maybe its something very simple I'm missing? Please see below code:

tb1legBW.text = This is the bag weight I'm referring too.

```
// This is setting the textbox values to 0 if they are blank. 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegOEW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegPW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegBW.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegFW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegFuel.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegEquip.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegAWI.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegFB.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegCont.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegMTOW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegGW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegGD.Text) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegMLW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegLW.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb1LegLGD.Text))

        {
            tb1LegOEW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegPW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegBW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegFW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegFuel.Text = "0";
            tb1LegEquip.Text = "0";
            tb1LegAWI.Text = "0";
            tb1LegFB.Text = "0";
            tb1LegCont.Text = "0";
            tb1LegMTOW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegGW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegGD.Text = "0";
            tb1LegMLW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegLW.Text = "0";
            tb1LegLGD.Text = "0";
        }
```

When I run the program the bag weight textbox is blank, unlike the others. Picture is attached: [When Program is ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hphlx.png)

If someone could please give me some insight on what is happening?

Comment: Could it have whitespace?  Also which name corresponds to that text box?

Comment: Your going to need to use the debugger to track this down, there's not enough code really say much other then it seems to me that if you want a form to have default values, you would set them in the editor and your done so I'm not sure why this is needed.

Comment: I tried nullwhitespaces and same result. I will have to look into the debugger as well look into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.IsNullOrWhitespace()

Comment: I did try this and same result.

Comment: Put the whole code inside the lost focus event. and if didn't work the error is not related to this part of code